# Explode list of tuples in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-explode

I am trying to explode a dataframe where one column consists of tuples. While it works well in cases where the tuples are of type string, but it does not work with when the tuples are integers.
Especially, I cannot assert that the expected result is similar to exploded result in the later case.

```
import pandas as pd

def explode_tuples(df):
    """explodes columns that consist only of tuples"""
    df_explode = df.copy(deep=True)
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype == object and set(df[col].apply(lambda x: type(x)).unique()) == {tuple, }:
            df_explode = df_explode.explode(col, ignore_index=True)

    return df_explode

def test_explode_tuples_correct():
    test_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [('1', '2'), ('3', '4')]})
    expected = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'B': ['1', '2', '3', '4']})
    exploded = explode_tuples(test_df)
    assert expected.equals(exploded)

def test_explode_tuples_failure():
    test_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [(1, 2), (3, 4)]})
    expected = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
    exploded = explode_tuples(test_df)
    assert expected.equals(exploded)
```

I know that is has something to do with the integers, but...

Answer (score 1):

The results of an `explode` operation are of type `object`.  In your first case, that's OK, because strings are also of type `object`.  In your second case, it results in a mismatch, because the incoming column is of type `tuple of int64`.

You can use an `astype` operation to convert the second column back to `int64`.  If you print the two dfs, you'll see that it is the same data.

Comment: `exploded.convert_dtypes()` could be an automatic alternative, note that the resulting type is `Int64` (not `int64`).